# Can more than one net be used on a creature? If so, how does a creature escape?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

If the first party member uses inspiration to land a net, the rest of the party can throw their nets without disadvantage. Would a single strength check remove all nets?

Answer (score 0):

### Depends on the DM

PHB page 148 describes the properties of a Net:

> A Large or smaller creature hit by a net is restrained until it is freed. (...) A creature can use its action to make a DC 10 Strength check, freeing itself or another creature within its reach on a success. Dealing 5 slashing damage to the net (AC 10) also frees the creature without harming it, ending the effect and destroying the net. (...)

What happens to a creature when it has multiple nets thrown at it? It is restrained and has multiple nets on itself, and that's about it. The only game effect here is the Restrained condition, applied only once, since conditions do not stack.

How does such a creature free itself? According to the description above, a DC 10 Strength check or dealing 5 slashing damage to the net **frees the creature**, which could be understood in two ways: "removes the Restrained condition", or "removes the single net the action was taken upon". Those are the same if it's the last net the creature is freed from, but with multiple ones there can be some discussion on which of the two interpretations apply.

My rule would be the first one presented, but I'd probably make it harder to free oneself from multiple nets at once, either by increasing the DC on the Strength check or the AC or hp of the nets, or imposing disadvantage on the check or attack. You could also get closer to the second interpretation and require that every net be dealt with separately, though maybe allow for removing multiple nets at the same time on a really high Strength check or a high-damage attack. My proposition here is +1 net per each 5 points above the DC or each 5 points of damage.